# subset() of a vector in R

Tags: r, subset

I've written the following function based on `subset()`, which I find handy:

```
ss <- function (x, subset, ...) 
{
    r <- eval(substitute(subset), data.frame(.=x), parent.frame())
    if (!is.logical(r)) 
        stop("'subset' must be logical")
    x[r & !is.na(r)]
}
```

So, I can write:

```
ss(myDataFrame$MyVariableName, 500 < . & . < 1500)
```

instead of

```
myDataFrame$MyVariableName[ 500 < myDataFrame$MyVariableName 
                                & myDataFrame$MyVariableName < 1500]
```

This seems like something other people might have developed solutions for, though - including something in core R I might have missed.  Anything already out there?

Comment: It still seems to work if we change `data.frame(.=x)` to `list(.=x)` and I suspect performance will improve.

Comment: To clarify - I just used `myDataFrame$MyVariableName` as an example of a very long vector name.  I probably should have used `myVeryVeryVeryLongVariableName` or something, but if I edit it now, @joran's answer won't make much sense. =)

Answer (score 4):

I realize that the solution Ken offers is more general than just selecting items within ranges (since it should work on any logical expression) but this did remind me that Greg Snow has comparison infix operators in his Teaching Demos package:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
x0 <- rnorm(100)
x0[ 0 %<% x0 %<% 1.5 ]
```

Comment: Cool!  I've always wanted an `x < y < z` construct too.

Comment: I remember when Perl got such a thing - they realized that they already had a fatal error saying "You've used 'x < y < z', which you must rewrite as 'x < y && y < z'", and realized how silly it was to not just DWIM.

Comment: Note that `a < x < b` is equivalent to `abs(x-mean(c(a,b))) < (b-mean(c(a,b)))`

Comment: @James handy when you only want to evaluate `x` once.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing Ken.

You could use:

```
x <- myDataFrame$MyVariableName; x[x > 100 & x < 180]
```

Yours may require less typing but the code is less generalizable to others if you're sharing code.  I have a few time saver functions like that myself but use them sparingly because they may be slowing down your code (extra steps) and requires you to also include that code for that function when ever you share the file with someone else.

**Compare writing length.  Almost the same length:**

```
ss(mtcars$hp, 100 < . & . < 180)
x <- mtcars$hp; x[x > 100 & x < 180]
```

**Compare time on 1000 replications.**

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
       tyler = x[x > 100 & x < 180],
       ken = ss(mtcars$hp, 100 <. & . < 180),
 replications=1000)

   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2   ken         1000    0.56 18.66667      0.36     0.03         NA        NA
1 tyler         1000    0.03  1.00000      0.03     0.00         NA        NA
```

So I guess it depends on if you need speed and/or sharability vs convenience.  If it's just for you on a small data set I'd say it's valuable.

**EDIT:  NEW BENCHMARKING**

```
> benchmark(
+     tyler = {x <- mtcars$hp; x[x > 100 & x < 180]}, 
+     ken = ss(mtcars$hp, 100 <. & . < 180), 
+     ken2 = ss2(mtcars$hp, 100 <. & . < 180),
+     joran = with(mtcars,hp[hp>100 & hp< 180 ]), 
+  replications=10000)

   test replications elapsed  relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
4 joran        10000    0.83  2.677419      0.69     0.00         NA        NA
2   ken        10000    3.79 12.225806      3.45     0.02         NA        NA
3  ken2        10000    0.67  2.161290      0.35     0.00         NA        NA
1 tyler        10000    0.31  1.000000      0.20     0.00         NA        NA
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too - it's essentially what I'm doing inside my `ss()` function, of course, but my `x` is named `.`.

Comment: As for speed, I took @DWin's suggestion and saw about a 10x improvement on this benchmark.  `benchmark(
        tyler = {x <- mtcars$hp; x[x > 100 & x < 180]},
        ken = ss(mtcars$hp, 100 <. & . < 180),
        ken2 = ss2(mtcars$hp, 100 <. & . < 180),+  replications=10000)
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2   ken        10000    2.26 15.06667      2.25        0         NA        NA
3  ken2        10000    0.24  1.60000      0.25        0         NA        NA
1 tyler        10000    0.15  1.00000      0.15        0         NA        NA`

Comment: gah, that's not pretty at all!

Comment: The other thing I changed in that benchmark was to include the assignment to `x` in the `tyler` code.

Comment: Ken just add the code to your original post or as an answer at the bottom

Comment: I definitely agree with your sentiment about non-sharability though, which is why I wondered if there was something already in the core.

Comment: I rerun the benchmark code in R 3.0.3. .......................................................................................................
`test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
4 joran        10000    0.19    1.357      0.18        0         NA        NA
2   ken        10000    1.56   11.143      1.56        0         NA        NA
3  ken2        10000    0.19    1.357      0.19        0         NA        NA
1 tyler        10000    0.14    1.000      0.14        0         NA        NA`