# R: Removing vector entries from a list of vectors after comparison using operator

Tags: r, list, vector

I'm trying to remove elements smaller than a given number from the vectors contained in a list. I manage to find exactly which elements in the vector meet my criteria, but somehow I'm failing to select them.

```
myList <- list(1:7,4:7,5:10)
lapply(myList, function(x)`>`(x ,5))
...
Rmagic
...
desiredoutput <- list(6:7,6:7,6:10)
```

I'm sure it's something to do with `[` but I can't figure it out and searching for this problem is a nightmare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subset() of a vector in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933431/subset-of-a-vector-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to extract the elements based on the logical index (`x>=6`)

```
lapply(myList, function(x) x[x>= 6])
```